# Firestore get DocumentSnapshot's field's value

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a Firebase Firestore database which I have retrieved a `DocumentSnapshot` for the document corresponding to the collection on the right and stored in a `document` variable, then how could I retrieve the value in that `DocumentSnapshot` at the field "username"?  The field has a string value.

[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) has a method [getString()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getString(java.lang.String)) which takes the name of a field and returns its value as a String.

```
String value = document.getString("username");
```

Comment: When I use this code, AndroidStudio does a red underline with `Incompatible types, Required:  java.lang.String, found java.lang.Object` Why would it be giving a generic Object?

Comment: You're probably getting a generic Object because the field doesn't have a String. Can you post a screenshot of your document in the Firestore console?

Comment: Updated with screenshot

Comment: @Paradox use get string not get

Answer (score 18):

you can use `get` method to get value of a field

```
String username = (String) document.get("username");  //if the field is String
Boolean b = (Boolean) document.get("isPublic");       //if the field is Boolean
Integer i = (Integer) document.get("age")             //if the field is Integer
```

checkout the doc for [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot)

Comment: This is the standard as per Web9, Modular.

Comment: How would you get the array values? or objects?

Answer (score 11):

You need to do a `DocumentReference` to get the content in your document.

A simple one will be like this.

```
DocumentReference docRef = myDB.collection("users").document("username");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document != null) {
                         Log.i("LOGGER","First "+document.getString("first"));
                         Log.i("LOGGER","Last "+document.getString("last"));
                         Log.i("LOGGER","Born "+document.getString("born"));
                    } else {
                         Log.d("LOGGER", "No such document");
                    }
               } else {
                    Log.d("LOGGER", "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
          }
     });
```

The downside is that you need to know your document ID to get the field values.

Answer (score 2):

I can only reference the field's data as Strings when I am inside the onComplete, but when I try reference it outside it. I get a nullPointerException and it crashes my activity.

```
// Gets user document from Firestore as reference
    DocumentReference docRef = mFirestore.collection("users").document(userID);

    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                    Log.d(TAG, "db firstName getString() is: " + document.getString("firstName"));
                    Log.d(TAG, "db lastName getString() is: " + document.getString("lastName"));

                    mFirstName = (String) document.getString("firstName");
                    mLastName = (String) document.getString("lastName");
                    Log.d(TAG, "String mFirstName is: " + mFirstName);
                    Log.d(TAG, "String mLastName is: " + mLastName);

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });

    //string checking outside the docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener code
    //commented it out because it causes a java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    //Log.v("NAME", mFirstName);
    //Log.v("NAME", mLastName);

    // sets the text on the TextViews
    tvFirstName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
    tvFirstName.setText(mFirstName);
    tvLastName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLastName);
    tvLastName.setText(mLastName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another simple way to get document value(in your case):

```
Firestore.instance
.collection('users').document('xsajAansjdna')
.get()
.then((value) =>
print("Fetched ==>>>"+value.data["username"]));
```

Comment: The point is that this is not performant, because you get whole the document, not just the desired field.

Answer (score 1):

```
`Firestore.instance
.collection('users').document('xsajAansjdna')
.get()
.then((value) =>
print("Fetched ==>>>"+value.data()["username"]));`
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.