# Could you help me to use Tools-Firebase in Android Studio to get me one of the Data on my Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Excuse me，Could you help me to use Tools-Firebase in Android Studio to get one of the Data on my Firebase Cloud Firestore? I am a beginner, I watched many video and still can't do it .(I use java in android studio.)

[image]

Comment: Did you try anything yet. If not, I recommend starting with the relevant Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data. If you did, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) that @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, I would suggest you to take a look at the answers of these Stackoverflow questions, showing how to get the value of a specific field of a document:

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55284162/11928130)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48493020/11928130)